# Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: spring, jboss

I have a J2EE based web application which perfectly gets deployed on JBoss 6.0 app server.
I am using JBoss's "default" server configuration.
My ".ear" file contains EJBs and a ".war" file - I am using Spring Security 3x for user authentication and authorization.

When I deploy the same ear file on JBoss 6.1, I find my WAR deployment fails with following errors. Surprising thing is: if I deploy the same ".ear" file in exploded format, then the deployment is successful.

```
22:31:14,827 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.3
22:31:14,828 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler EdmQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
22:31:14,828 INFO  [QuartzService] QuartzService(EdmQuartzMBean) started.
22:31:14,837 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/edm
22:31:14,896 INFO  [[/edm]] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
22:31:14,897 INFO  [ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
22:31:14,907 INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 21 22:31:14 PDT 2011]; rootof context hierarchy
22:31:14,910 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-business.xml]
22:31:14,911 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-business.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-business.xml]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3369) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_27]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_27]
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at $Proxy41.start(Unknown Source)       at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:53) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:41) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

In my WAR's web.xml I have specified Spring configuration file locations as:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
         /WEB-INF/applicationContext-business.xml
         /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have verified that the XML files do not have any syntax issue and those files are indeed packaged under WAR's WEB-INF directory. 
Now I believe JBoss uses Tomcat which unpacks the WAR file. So it seems that the files cannot be found on the classpath when the WAR file is loaded and/or it is not being unpacked.

I have no clue how it successfully works in JBoss 6.0 but fails on 6.1.
There are more bug fixes in 6.1 but internal structure or libraries are not changed between these 2 releases.

Can anyone please suggest why Spring cannot find those configuration files when the "ear" is deployed in archived/collapsed format?
Do I need to package such configuration files under WEB-INF/classes or should I use any prefix like "classpath:" in  tags?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know we can fix this by adding the files in class path and changing the web.xml to

```
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
     classpath:/resource/applicationContext-business.xml
   </param-value>
 </context-param>
```